# allow splits to have 0 width and height

Tags: vim-windows, split

Any way to do this? I'm attaching a pic so you can see what I mean. There is one column on the left that I can't get rid of when re-sizing the split.

[image: a busy cat]

I want the dashed bar to go all the way to the side so I can't see the tildes on the left.

Comment: You can play with `:help 'winminheight'` and `:help 'winminwidth'`.

Comment: @romainl Interestingly enough, setting `winminwidth` to 0 works for me, but not setting `winminheight` to 0.

Answer (score 3):

thanks to romainl in the comments above I found the answer, just put:

```
set winminheight=0
set winminwidth=0
```

in your `.vimrc`